# How can I remove the new back-to-previous-app iOS 9 button from my app?

Tags: ios, cordova, facebook-ios-sdk, ios9

For example, when a user logs in to my app with Facebook, I open the Facebook app for auth, and then the Facebook app switches back to my app. But from then on, "Back to Facebook" stays in the top-left.

Comment: Any luck in finding the solution?

Answer (score 4):

At this time, I do it by hiding status bar. I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Any luck in finding the solution?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK No luck :(! I shall update this post as soon as I get one!